# PHP function inside another function cannot reference `$this`

Tags: php

I have a function inside a function and the inner function cannot find the outer class. I don't know why. I hope someone has an idea how I can solve this. I don't want to declare the inner function outside of the outer function.

```
class Foo {

    public $test = "test123";

    private function outerfunction(){

        function innerfunction(){

            echo $this->test;

        }

        innerfunction();

    }

}
```

if I call the inner function I get the error `Using $this when not in object context`.

Comment: So pass it in as an argument

Comment: i dont can use this as default parameter, and i dont want include this everytime in this function

Comment: You are less likely to use inner functions in classes.  These would more likely be private or protected functions in the class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just restructure it to an anonymous function:

```
$innerfunction = function () {
    echo $this->test;
}

$innerfunction();
```

The class context is then automatically bound to the function (see also http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
Be aware, that this only works for >= PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare it as a variable, or it will tell you that you aren't in an object context:

```
    $innerfunction = function() {

        echo $this->test;

    };
    call_user_func($innerfunction);
```

Alternatively, you can keep the function as you do, and pass it the object context since it's known at the call point:

```
    function innerfunction(/* Foo */ $obj) {

        echo $obj->test;

    };
    innerfunction($this);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most glaring issue with this approach is that calling `outerFunction()` more than once will produce:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare innerfunction()...

Another issue is that `innerfunction()` is declared in the global scope. If this is intentional then that is highly unconventional and you probably should not do that. Anyways, it allows for this:

```
class Foo {

    public $test = "test123";

    public function outerfunction(){

        function innerfunction(){
            //echo $this->test;
        }

        innerfunction();
    }
}

$a = new foo();

// innerfunction(); // NOPE!
$a->outerFunction();
innerfunction(); // YES
```

So, this is the logical way to declare `innerfunction()`:

```
class Foo {

    public $test = "test123";

    public function outerfunction(){
        $this->innerfunction();
    }

    private function innerfunction(){
        echo $this->test;
    }
}

$a = new foo();

$a->outerFunction();
```